# Jquery AJAX returns an error even though the same URL will return content. Why is that?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a jquery AJAX request calling a webservice with the result string being returned = "Tested!".  WHen I do the request though the url, it returns: {"testResult":"Tested!"} which makes sense to me.

My error is that the jQuery AJAX request, will hit the webservice, hit a breakpoint, and return string, but then still hit the error code instead of success.

The error code is as follows:

```
 //function(xhr,status,message)
 xhr.statusText = success
 status = parseerror
 message: Error Jquery17204...   was not called.
```

Below is my AJAX request.  Maybe there is something wrong which i am not getting, which is causing the returned code to error.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: WEBSERVICE_URL + '/test',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //success
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                var r = $(result.getWebFormDesignFieldContentsResult)[0];
                var div = $("<div class='modal'>").html(r.d);
                /*
                var d = document.createElement("div");
                d.className = "modal";
                d.appendChild(r[0]);
                */
                $("div.modal").replaceWith(div);
                $("div.modal #queryInput").val(opts);
                $("div.modal").css({
                    top: $(window).height() / 2 - $("div.modal").height() / 2,
                    left: $(window).width() / 2 - $("div.modal").width() / 2
                });
                $("div.modal").fadeIn();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, message) {
                //error
                //alert("Error: "+result.statusText);
                alert("Error: " + status + " " + message);

                //$("div.modal").replaceWith($("<div class = 'modal'>").html(result.responseText));
                //$("div.modal").fadeIn();
                $("div.overlay").fadeOut();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is `WEBSERVICE_URL`? Is it on a different domain or port than the page running this script? Is it returning valid jsonp? (the jsonp you showed us above is json, not jsonp)

Comment: You're saying that the AJAX call returns JSONP data (`dataType: 'jsonp'`) - is that actually the case? If it is, then jQuery will handle parsing it for you, you shouldn't need to do `result = JSON.parse(result);` in your success callback function.

Comment: different domain....   i have 2 servers running on different ports.

Comment: i noticed that when i was calling the file, that the console is spitting out an error:  SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' 
test?callback=jQuery1720031804220563972696_1341848600377&_=1341848935765, line 1 character 14

Comment: The item reference i believe is to the return content, which in this case is the data:  {"testResult":"Tested!"}

Comment: If JSONP is what i need to use (my operationsContract says that the responseFormat is going to be JSON.  THe only other option for that is XML.  Is there another way to do it other then dealing with this while just using JSON instead of JSONP?  It IS using a different port so i am thinking that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a JSONP call, so the result returned from the server has to look like this:

```
Jquery17204({"testResult":"Tested!"})
```

The server should take the query string `callback` and use as the function name. In this case the AJAX request sent `callback=Jquery17204`.

Comment: the webservice is returning a string as per the definition: 
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "test")]
        string test();

Comment: how would i adjust the operationContract so that it is doing what you ask?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Yes, the server is returning a JSON response, but you need a JSONP response. The `WebMessageFormat` only contains XML and JSON, so you have to use some completely different way to return the JSONP result.

Comment: awww. ok.  What would you reccomend?   Adjust it to be an XML result returned and then just parse it for the string i want?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: If the service is in the same domain, you can just change the request to use JSON instead of JSONP. If it's in another domain, neither JSON nor XML will work.

Comment: what is the definition of domain?  For example for me, it will be localhost with 2 different port references.  With that said, without looking further, It would be the same, different ports.  I didnt know if ports defined the domain, or the context of "localhost" being the domain and not the ports.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: In most browsers the port is included. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy